# How can I hide a text box inside jQuery loop without appending to td or tr

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here is my code:

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {

                               tr = $('<tr/>');


tr.append($("<td/>").html('<label >'+item['ITEM_NAME']+'</label>'));

tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="hidden" name="item_id" class="item_id" value="'+item['ITEM_ID']+'"/>'));

)};

$('#tbl_items').append(tr);

<table id="tbl_items"></table>
```

How can I hide text box "item_id" without appending to    td or  tr?

Comment: "hide text box "item_id" without appending" if you don't append it then it wouldn't show? can you give more details about the problem?

Comment: If i am not appending to <td> nothing will displaying on the page.

Comment: @Learner If i am using your code i cant retrieve the value of hidden text field ('item_id')

Comment: Item_id is not a text box, but a hidden input value. It's shown never. What would you hide then?

Comment: @Don hidden field already hidden you don't need to hide it. where you want to access it can you show code where you trying to get its value?

Comment: When i hide a textbox by appending it to <td> a blank column is displaying in the page while running the project

Comment: @Learner I have edited my code please go through it.

Comment: i can't see any textbox in your code its hidden field